# halloweenmath package not working

Tags: pdftex, packages, compilation-error

I am trying to use the symbols from the `halloweenmath` package for a deck of slides. It works if I only define a symbol once or twice, but compilation fails (both on MikTeX and Overleaf) when too many symbols are used. See MWE below. Any idea what the problem could be?

Non-working MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{halloweenmath}
\title{Paper Title}
\author{\normalsize{Author 1$^{\pumpkin ,\mathbat}$ \\ \scriptsize (joint with Author 2$^{\mathghost, c, \skull}$, Author 3$^{\mathwitch}$, Author 4,$^{\mathghost}$ Author 5$^{\mathghost, \mathbat}$}\\
\medskip
\tiny{$^{\pumpkin}$Instituation A\\
$^{\mathghost}$Instituation B\\
$^{\mathbat}$ Instituation C\\  
$^{\skull}$Instituation D\\
$^{\mathwitch}$Instituation E\\
}}
\date{\normalsize{Some Event\\
October 28, 2021}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Working MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{halloweenmath}
\title{Paper Title}
\author{\normalsize{Author 1$^{\pumpkin ,b}$ \\ \scriptsize (joint with Author 2$^{b, c, d}$, Author 3$^{e}$, Author 4,$^{b}$ Author 5$^{b, c}$}\\
\medskip
\tiny{$^{\pumpkin}$Instituation A\\
$^{b}$Instituation B\\
$^{c}$ Instituation C\\ 
$^{d}$Instituation D\\
$^{e}$Instituation E\\
}}
\date{\normalsize{Some Event\\
October 28, 2021}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`beamer` tries to expand the author to set the pdfauthor key. As you don't want (can't have) the halloween math there the best is to suppress this and to set the pdfauthor manually:

```
\documentclass[usepdftitle=false]{beamer} %don't try to guess the pdfauthor
\usepackage{halloweenmath}
\title{Paper Title}

\author{\normalsize{Author 1$^{\pumpkin ,\mathbat}$ \\ \scriptsize (joint with Author 2$^{\mathghost, c, \skull}$, Author 3$^{\mathwitch}$, Author 4,$^{\mathghost}$ Author 5$^{\mathghost, \mathbat}$}\\
\medskip
\tiny{$^{\pumpkin}$Instituation A\\
$^{\mathghost}$Instituation B\\
$^{\mathbat}$ Instituation C\\
$^{\skull}$Instituation D\\
$^{\mathwitch}$Instituation E\\
}}

\hypersetup{pdfauthor=something normal}

\date{\normalsize{Some Event\\
October 28, 2021}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Side remark: commands like `\normalsize` or `\tiny` don't take an argument, they are switches.

[image]